# How to press ENTER with AutoItX on Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, autoit

I'm trying to build automation script with Selenium(Java) + AutoItX.
In my script I want to press the ENTER key, this is my code:

```
AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    x.send("{ENTER}");
```

but it doesn't work.. any idea why?

Comment: Did you tried `x.send("{ENTER}", false);` ?

Comment: @Pivoman Yes, didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use below code.

```
x.controlSend(windowTitle, "", mainOutlookClass, "{ENTER}");
```

WindowTitle = Window Name

mainOutlookClass = Class name of that window, which you can find from AutoIT.